# What am I missing here to get data out of this spawned Node.js child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, spawn

I'm trying to use a spawned command-line `lzip` process to expand an lzipped data stream, as I haven't found any good native JavaScript tools to do the job.

I can get this to work using files and file descriptors, but it seems stupid to have to write out, and read back in, a bunch of temporary scratch files. I want to do all of the work I can in memory.

So here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
import { requestBinary } from 'by-request';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import { min } from '@tubular/math';

export async function tarLzToZip(url: string): Promise<void> {
  const lzData = await requestBinary(url, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.64.1' } });
  const lzipProc = spawn('lzip', ['-d'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stderr] });
  let tarContent = Buffer.alloc(0);

  lzipProc.stdout.on('data', data => {
    tarContent = Buffer.concat([tarContent, data], tarContent.length + data.length);
  });

  for (let offset = 0; offset < lzData.length; offset += 4096) {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      lzipProc.stdin.write(lzData.slice(offset, min(offset + 4096, lzData.length)), err => {
        if (err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    lzipProc.stdin.end((err: any) => {
      if (err)
        reject(err);
      else
        resolve();
    });
  });

  console.log('data length:', tarContent.length);
}
```

When I step through with a debugger everything seems to be going well with the sending data into `lzipProc.stdin`. (I've tried doing both chunks like this, and all data in one go.) `lzipProc.stdout.on('data', data =>`, however, never gets called. When I get to the end, `tarContent` is empty.

What's missing here? Do I need a different `stdio` config? Are there different stream objects I should be using? Do I need to more goats to sacrifice under the light of a full moon?

**UPDATE**

My solution based on Matt's excellent answer posted below, with all of the particulars for my use case:

```
import archiver from 'archiver';
import fs, { ReadStream } from 'fs';
import fsp from 'fs/promises';
import needle from 'needle';
import path from 'path';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import tar from 'tar-stream';

const baseUrl = 'https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/';

export async function codeAndDataToZip(version: string): Promise<ReadStream> {
  return compressedTarToZip(`${baseUrl}tzdb-${version}.tar.lz`);
}

export async function codeToZip(version: string): Promise<ReadStream> {
  return compressedTarToZip(`${baseUrl}tzcode${version}.tar.gz`);
}

export async function dataToZip(version: string): Promise<ReadStream> {
  return compressedTarToZip(`${baseUrl}tzdata${version}.tar.gz`);
}

async function compressedTarToZip(url: string): Promise<ReadStream> {
  const fileName = /([-a-z0-9]+)\.tar\.[lg]z$/i.exec(url)[1] + '.zip';
  const filePath = path.join(process.env.TZE_ZIP_DIR || path.join(__dirname, 'tz-zip-cache'), fileName);

  if (await fsp.stat(filePath).catch(() => false))
    return fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  const [command, args] = url.endsWith('.lz') ? ['lzip', ['-d']] : ['gzip', ['-dc']];
  const originalArchive = needle.get(url, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.64.1' } });
  const tarExtract = tar.extract({ allowUnknownFormat: true });
  const zipPack = archiver('zip');
  const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  const commandProc = spawn(command, args);

  commandProc.stderr.on('data', msg => { throw new Error(`${command} error: ${msg}`); });
  commandProc.stderr.on('error', err => { throw err; });

  originalArchive.pipe(commandProc.stdin);
  commandProc.stdout.pipe(tarExtract);

  tarExtract.on('entry', (header, stream, next) => {
    zipPack.append(stream, { name: header.name, date: header.mtime });
    stream.on('end', next);
  });

  tarExtract.on('finish', () => zipPack.finalize());
  zipPack.pipe(writeFile);

  return new Promise<ReadStream>((resolve, reject) => {
    const rejectWithError = (err: any): void =>
      reject(err instanceof Error ? err : new Error(err.message || err.toString()));

    writeFile.on('error', rejectWithError);
    writeFile.on('finish', () => resolve(fs.createReadStream(filePath)));
    tarExtract.on('error', err => {
      // tar-stream has a problem with the format of a few of the tar files
      // dealt with here, which nevertheless are valid archives.
      if (/unexpected end of data|invalid tar header/i.test(err.message))
        console.error('Archive %s: %s', url, err.message);
      else
        reject(err);
    });
    zipPack.on('error', rejectWithError);
    zipPack.on('warning', rejectWithError);
    commandProc.on('error', rejectWithError);
    commandProc.on('exit', err => err && reject(new Error(`${command} error: ${err}`)));
    originalArchive.on('error', rejectWithError);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to recompress the stream after this decompression as well? It might be easier to keep it all as a stream between commands and just resolve at the end of everything.

Comment: I don't think (I could be wrong, and my Unix-fu is just too weak) I could create a single command line that would do all of this. lzip piped into tar (for untarring) would be fine, but I don't think tar produces, as a single stream, all of the separate directories and files a tar archive contains in such a format that it could be piped into a zip command.

And even if I did know how to do that, I don't think Node's exec function would handle all of that piping in a single line.

Comment: oh yeah, not straight unix for the zip repackage.  Node does have [tar-stream](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream) that would let you process each file from the tar. And [archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver)/[zip-stream](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-zip-stream) to repackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the streaming to node or packages, unless you have specific processing that needs to be done. Just wrap the whole stream setup in a promise.

If you also stream the request/response, it can be piped into the decompresser. Then `stdout` from the decompressor can be piped to the archive stream handlers.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import { spawn } from 'child_process'
import needle from 'needle'
import tar from 'tar-stream'
import archiver from 'archiver'

export function tarLzToZip(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Setup streams
    const res = needle.get(url)
    const lzipProc = spawn('lzip', ['-dc'], { stdio: ['pipe','pipe',process.stderr] })
    const tarExtract = tar.extract()
    const zipPack = archiver('zip')
    const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream('tardir.zip')

    // Pipelines and processing
    res.pipe(gzipProc.stdin)
    lzipProc.stdout.pipe(tarExtract)
    // tar -> zip (simple file name)
    tarExtract.on('entry', function(header, stream, next) {
      console.log('entry', header)
      zipPack.append(stream, { name: header.name })
      stream.on('end', () => next())
    })
    tarExtract.on('finish', function() {
      zipPack.finalize()
    })
    zipPack.pipe(writeFile)

    // Handle the things
    writeFile.on('error', reject)
    writeFile.on('close', () => console.log('write close'))
    writeFile.on('finish', resolve(true))
    tarExtract.on('error', reject)
    zipPack.on('error', reject)
    zipPack.on('warning', reject)
    lzipProc.on('error', reject)
    lzipProc.on('exit', code => {if (code !== 0) reject(new Error(`lzip ${code}`))})
    res.on('error', reject)
    res.on('done', ()=> console.log('request done', res.request.statusCode))
  })
}
```

You might want to be a bit more verbose about logging errors and stderr as the singular promise `reject` can easily hide what actually happened across the multiple streams.

Comment: Looks like a good general approach for the parts I haven't written yet, but as is this doesn't handle the lzip format. I could only find one Node lzip library, but it had no documentation at all, very few downloads, no source web site... needless to say I didn't trust it. I did, by the way, try `gzip -dc tzdb-2021a.tar.lz`, but just got the error message "gzip: tzdb-2021a.tar.lz: not in gzip format".

Comment: I might have commented too quickly, and should interpreted your code as something to re-interpret with the lzip command replacing your spawned gzip. I'll let you know how it goes. And thanks for the help so far. :)

Comment: Yeah sorry no `lzip` here to test. I'll edit

Comment: @kshetline is it `-dc` to stdout or is just `-d` ok?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I used just '-d' for the lzip options. After I flesh out all of the error handling and stuff, I'll post back the final code as an update to my question. One weird issue I have to deal with, that I know from previous use of tar-stream, is that tar-stream throws an error when it reaches the end of some of the archives I'm handling, even though the archives are valid, so I need to ignore errors sometimes.

Comment: I've now posted my updated code based on your solution.